# How to resolve Java EE Bad Practices: Direct Management of Connections

Tags: java, jdbc, security, veracode

I submitted my Java application EAR to Veracode Security testing tool and got API Abuse- Direct Mangament of Connection flaw in the below code:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (url, hsUserId, hsPassword);
```

Someone please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Your error messages states it pretty clearly:

> Direct Mangament of Connection flaw

So within a container you should never create connections by hand, but let the container do it.

You speak of "J2EE", or are you instead mean "Java EE"? (You should add the related tag!)

In the 1st case, you'll have to do a JNDI lookup:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource datasource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("..");
Connection conn = datasource.getConnection();
```

In the 2nd case, you annotate it and let it inject:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;
```